# SSh remote tunnel, am I missing something?

Tags: linux, ssh, vps

I want to make a local port that serve a python http.server accessible to the internet without messing around with port-forwarding on my home router, tunnelling it on a digital ocean vps.
My local port is 8080, the port on the remote vps 4444, just for example

ssh -i .ssh/mykey -R 4444:localhost:8080 root@myvpsip

But still http://myvpsip:4444 is not accessible

ufw is disabled on the vps..What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

For the forwarded port to listen on any address (and not just `localhost`) you need to prepend an additional `:` to the forward specification.

```
ssh -i .ssh/mykey -R :4444:localhost:8080 root@myvpsip
```

Additionally, you must have `GatewayPorts yes` or `GatewayPorts clientspecified` on the server-side sshd configuration.